# Keep Adding to NSMutable Array

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I am pretty new to Objective-C, and trying to create a to-do list app with a table view. I am trying to keep adding strings to my mutable array as the button is pressed. But each time I press the button only the last string gets added to the array.

```
- (IBAction)notebutton:(UIButton *)sender {

   NSMutableArray *mystr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
   NSString *name = _noteField.text;
   [mystr addObject:name];
   [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: you should create array outside the method and initialize, then add strings to array in method noteButton:

Comment: Yea that makes sense but where would be a good place to create the array?

Comment: you can make it in viewDidLoad. just declare it in your .h file and make initilization in viewDidLoad

Comment: it is explained in answer below very well

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do not declare the `NSMutableArray` each time. Declare it only once.

Make `NSMutableArray *mystr;` as a property and allocate it in `viewDidLoad()` once.

in **.h** or **.m** file

```
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSMutableArray *mystr;
```

**viewDidLoad()**

```
self.mystr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

- (IBAction)notebutton:(UIButton *)sender {

   NSString *name = _noteField.text;
   [self.mystr addObject:name];
   [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: then I get this error "Initializer element is not a compile-time constant"

Answer (score 0):

You Are creating mutable array on method. so each time its Allocating and making new array.

Just allocate the nsmutable array in viewdidload/viewdidappear and add object in your method.